# ARM processor + zynq-7000 compilation platform in Linux C++?

Tags: c++, compile, arm, register

I worked on a project that was built by C++ and compiled on a linux ARM based zynq-7000 platform. What kind of platform is this? I know a zynq-7000 (or UltraScale) is a newer FPGA. I also worked a lot on ARM processors using C++ before. When the two (ARM & zynq-7000) combined together to be a development platform in C++, how is this development platform structured ?

I read through the Internet: "ARM-based SoCs combine a hard ARM processor, memory controllers, and peripherals with customizable FPGA fabric in a single SoC" (https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/wp/wp-01167-custom-arm-soc.pdf). In this case, this SoC should be treated as a FPGA with an ARM processor, and the system design needs to be done via HDL.

However, in my development environment, ARM + zynq-7000 platform is treated very similar to x86 where I could compile and run my projects in C++.

Any thoughts on my confusion here?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That link is describing an ARM processor emulated ***within*** the FPGA fabric and is a way to create a fully functional processor with a custom mix of I/O as necessary. ARM is a popular emulation target due to being a common platform with readily available libraries. Programming for that emulated CPU would be done via C++, the actual CPU *core* would be programmed in VHDL. It would not be as efficient or as fast as a real CPU, but it can be more suited to any given task needing lots of I/Os or custom handling of data which can be done in the FPGA before being handed to the CPU core.

What you have in the Zync is a fully-fledged real world silicon ARM based CPU system that is running a full Linux distribution with an FPGA attached. Because you have a real CPU it is programmable via C++. It is essentially a full computer with FPGA built in.

Modern FPGA development platforms can also allow a subset of FGPA design to be done [via C++](https://www.netcope.com/en/company/press-center/press-releases/optimizing-trading-strategies-for-fpgas-in-c-c) instead of VHDL or VDL but the language is not suited for the FPGA architecture and some concessions need to be made.

The main intention of this kind of SoC is to allow the FPGA to be dynamically reflashed using control logic within the ARM processor instead of from a static memory. In this way the FPGA program can be updated much faster and changed to suit conditions in a much more dynamic way. The processor could be checking for FPGA firmware updates and applying fixes in seconds rather than needing to take the system offline to apply them, monitoring network conditions or other things, and update or reflash the FPGA to apply fixes "in situ" or to change behaviour entirely.

Comment: Is it a real, instead of emulated, ARM processor embedded as a SoC on the zynq-7000 FPGA board? All my C++ codes are compiled on the platform of "Arm + zynq-7000". I also have the choice of ARM processor only platform, but I am required to compile my program on the platform of "ARM + zynq-7000".

Comment: In the Zync, yes it is a real ARM processor. It is entirely possible that at least some of the compilation needs awareness of the SoC to be able to set up or work around the platform quirks. "ARM only" may not fully set up the environment for the processor with memory zones and addressing methods set up for all the peripherals and FPGA.

Comment: In this case, since FPGA and ARM SoC is a whole, I am guessing I should be able to use Vivado to program the zync-7000. Therefore, this Zync-7000 should show up in my hardware manager for programming by .bit file. Is this correct?

Comment: It depends. If the Zync FPGA is accessible to the host system then yes, but it might only be accessible to the ARM "host" that runs alongside it. You'd have to look in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations here. It helps a lot.